Why the term "quadratic"?
In mathematics, a quadratic equation is an equation that can be rearranged in standard form as $$ax^2+bx+c=0,$$ where $x$ represents an unknown value, and $a$, $b$, and $c$ represent known numbers, where $a \neq 0$.
So, basically, I am not a mathematician (in the strict sense of the term) but a physicist. So, I had a thought that the word "quad" means four. So, ad is an equation of order two called quadratic. It has a highest exponent of $2$ and also $2$ roots. So, how come the word "quadratic"?

quadratus in Latin means 'square' - from a simple Google search.

How many sides has a square?

Fourth power is called quartic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function

See also Why is it called a quadratic if it only contains $x^2$, not $x^4$? and, on the English Language Stackexchange, Why does "quadratic" describe second power when "quad" means "four"?.
